# Cоюз "или" в вопросительном предложении, соединяющий два ССП

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, сложное-предложение, ссп

*Рост курса доллара является временным[,] и уровень расходов вскоре нормализуется[,] или курс продолжит расти[,] и компания будет терпеть ещё бóльшие убытки?*

Когда союз "или" соединяет части вопросительного ССП, запятая не ставится. Но здесь союз "или" соединяет две части, которые в свою очередь сами являются ССП.

Как расставить запятые? Играет ли роль тот факт, что характер связи между частями в обеих парах не однородный, а условно-следственный?

Comment: А где знак вопроса?

Comment: @Ксения Исправил.

Answer (score 3):

**(1) Рост курса доллара является временным и (2) уровень расходов вскоре нормализУется или курс продолжит расти и компания будет терпеть ещё бОльшие убытки?**

У наших классиков такого примера нет, поэтому решать задачу надо самостоятельно.

Будем исходить из того, что предложения в составе ССП **может объединять интонация.**

Сложное предложение состоит из  двух ССП, связанных союзом ИЛИ. Каждое СПП состоит из двух простых предложений, **но произносится в одну фразу**, то есть их объединяет интонация.

Делить сложное предложение на четыре фразы не получится, так как основным грамматическим значением предложения является **отношение между двумя ССП**, именно его **надо выразить с помощью интонации и знаков препинания**. Для этого мы должны иметь только две интонационные фразы.

Поэтому запятых в этом предложении нет. Запятая перед союзом ИЛИ не ставится  по правилу общей вопросительной интонации. Пример из Розенталя: **Вы придёте ко мне или мне прийти к вам?**; http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Comment: Скажите, а условно-следственное значение союза «и» (а не значение перечисления) не влияет на постановку запятой? К примеру, если после каждого союза "и" добавить наречие "тогда", то запятая всё равно будет отсутствовать?

Comment: Здесь нет однородных соединительно-перечислительных отношений, так как такие отношения обозначают одновременные действия, а в вашем предложении  глаголы имеют разное время (настоящее и будущее). Это уже неоднородные соединительно-результативные (соединительно-следственные) отношения. Добавление наречия «тогда» мало что изменит.

Comment: Я про другое. Например, в этом предложении: "Мы думаем, что рост курса доллара является временным и уровень расходов вскоре нормализуется" — тот факт, что отношения между предложениями соединительно-следственные, а не чисто соединительные, не влияет на отсутствие запятой при общем элементе, общей главной части т. д.?

Comment: Предложения именно с такими отношениями удобно объединять в одну фразу. А вообще ССП с соединительными союзами делятся на группы: а) предложения однородного состава (соединительно-перечислительные отношения)  и предложения неоднородного состава (все остальные).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, запятые не нужны, но ответ скорее интуитивный. Мысли такие: здесь две пары и союз *или* между ними. Общей конструкции для каждой пары нет, но ее как будто объединяет то, что она противопоставлена другой паре.